# Subsonic many-to-many

Tags: subsonic, many-to-many

For Subsonic users,

is there a source of information about how to deal with many-to-many relations in Subsonic? I keep getting "***//no ManyToMany tables defined (0)***" in my generated code, although I have defined the right relations in database.

any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Kent Sharkey's example at http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/UsingSubSonicToCreateASimpleBogEngine.aspx.  Specifically, look at the section titled "Adding Category support".

Numerous times, I have setup the keys incorrectly which has caused SubSonic to not recognize the many-to-many relationship.  Make sure both fields make up a composite key.

Comment: it was the "Make sure both fields make up a composite key". thanks Michael